# Uniform Random on $(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution

Imagine picking a 1 when any real number is equally likely.  What is the pdf?  Does this idea have a known use?  What is its name?

There could be a use for a uniform random real number.  It could end up always being integrated.  It could be a prior for a number that is completely unknown.

It would be like a delta function, which integrates to a finite number though it doesn't have a well-defined value at zero.  The delta function is greater than any number at zero.   This uniform random on (-inf,inf) would be not well-defined anywhere.  It would be less than any positive number and greater than zero.  What is it?

Comment: Look up "improper distribution" or "improper prior."

Comment: It does have some names (it's sometimes used as an improper prior in Bayesian stats).

This is not actually possible as an actual probability distribution; you certainly can't generate from it.

Comment: I think you're wrong that it would "integrate to a finite number". If you had a uniform from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ it wouldn't converge; the area under the curve would be $\infty$.

Comment: @gung All these statements have to taken somewhat metaphorically: after all, a "delta function" is not a function and it is (evocative) nonsense to assert it is "greater than any number at zero." Formally, what's going on is a process of completing a function space. Delta functions arise as limits of absolute continuous probability densities as their essential support shrinks to a point; improper distributions arise as limits of a.c. densities that are rescaled arbitrarily greatly. As such, they "integrate" to unity in almost the same sense a delta function does.

Comment: Yep, an improper prior is indeed the thing. Like @whuber said, it isn't really a function, but it is a useful idea.  ---- How is it useful?  I don't know a particular case, but I've been trying to apply it to a case comparing a guessed value with a statistic (kind of like hypothesis testing, but somehow Bayesian because it doesn't assume there is an underlying true value I guess).  So far I've been able to get it so I don't have to evaluate it by itself, but rather I can evaluate the integral of it!

Comment: Here's where wikipedia gives this distribution as an example of an improper prior: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Examples)

Comment: Here's a relevant [draft article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1067) from the arXiv.

Answer (score 4):

We can also approach the matter as follows: Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real valued random variables following a uniform $U(-n,n)$ distribution. Does the sequence converge in distribution to a random variable?

Convergence in distribution means

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}(x) = F_X(x)$$

where the RHS is a distribution function, and the equality to hold for every $x$ for which  $F_X(x)$ is continuous.
Our distribution function is

$$F_{X_n}(x)= \begin{cases}0&\text{if $x<-n$}\\\frac{x+n}{2n}&\text{if $x\in[-n,n]$} \\1&\text{if $x> n$.}\end{cases}$$

The first and the last branch are not defined as $n\rightarrow \infty$, since there is no $x$ lower than "minus infinity", or higher than "plus infinity". Then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big (\frac{x}{2n} + \frac 12\Big) = 0+\frac 12$$

The constant function $1/2$ does not satisfy the [properties of a distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties), specifically

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\frac 12 =\frac 12 \neq 0,\;\;\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac 12 =\frac 12 \neq 1$$

The fundamental entity associated with a random variable is the cumulative distribution function, and not the probability density function. Since the limit of cdfs converges to a function that is not a cdf, the sequence does not converge to a random variable. Of course, as the comments indicated, this does not make it a useless concept, quite the contrary.

**ADDENDUM Feb 1, 2014.**
I found a nice piece of history related to this question: A.Rényi, in 
[Rényi, A. (1955). On a new axiomatic theory of probability. Acta Mathematica Hungarica, 6(3), 285-335.](http://www.akademiai.com/content/w86l5j157676kj25/) motivates his axiomatic formulation of probability in terms of conditional probability by writing (p.285), among other things that

> *"In the theory of KOLMOGOROV it has, for instance, no sense to speak
>   about a probability distribution which is uniform on the whole real axis or
>   on the whole plane, further it has no sense to say that we choose an integer
>   in such a way that all integers (or all non-negative integers) are equiprobable."*